# Path mappings in nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Here is my nginx conf file events {}

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend-app:4200;
        }

        location /auth {
            proxy_pass http://auth-service:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

When I type localhost:80, it is forwared to frontend-app:4200 with no problem. Similarly, when type localhost:80/auth, it is forwarded to auth-service:8080 with no problem. However, when I type localhost:80/auth/<some_path>, it is not forwarded to auth-service:8080/<some_path> . How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Just simply rewrite the location: `location /auth {
    rewrite ^/auth/?(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://auth-service:8080;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no optional URL, `proxy_pass` will pass the requested URL to the upstream proxy without modifying it.

For example, a request for `/auth/foo` sent to your server, will be passed to `http://auth-service:8080` as `/auth/foo`.

There are two ways to modify the URL before it is passed upstream: using the [built-in function of `proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) or [using `rewrite...break`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

For example:

```
location /auth/ {
    proxy_pass http://auth-service:8080/;
}
```

Notice that both the `location` value and the `proxy_pass` value must end with `/` for the correct mapping to work. This of coarse means that the URL `localhost:80/auth` will no longer work.

---

If you need both `localhost:80/auth` and `localhost:80/auth/foo` to work, you should use `rewrite...break`.

For example:

```
location /auth {
    rewrite ^/auth/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://auth-service:8080;
}
```

The above will work with or without a trailing `/` after `/auth`.